# Submit button sometimes executes the action twice in html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

In my HTML form when I click submit button it is disabled so a user can't click it twice. This button sends an email but when I test this form sometimes button executes the action twice although I click on it one time and sometimes it works right and executes the action only once. This is my code:

```
<form id="request-form" action="http://premitek.slayer.nabdsys.com/UserAccount/Create" class="contact-form">
    <input name="txt" id="txt" type="text"> 
    <input value="Sign up" 
           id="btnSignUp"
           onclick="goog_report_conversion();ToGetTrackingCode();"
           class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
           data-loading-text="Loading..." 
           type="submit">
</form>
```

```js
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    if ($('#CaptchaEnter').val().toLowerCase() != $('#randomfield').val().toLowerCase() || $('#CaptchaEnter').val() == "") {                   
        e.preventDefault();               
        $('#captcha').attr(
             "style", 
             "border-color: #a94442; box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px"
        );
        $('#verCapacha').show();
    } else {
        $('#captcha').attr("style","");
        $('#verCapacha').hide();
        $('#btnSignUp').prop('disabled', true);
        ShowProgress();
    }
});
```

Comment: As an aside, you should remove the `onclick` attribute and call `goog_report_conversion()` and `ToGetTrackingCode()` from within the `submit` handler too. Also, adding/removing classes instead of overwriting the `style` attribute on an element would be much better practice.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Do you think this causes the issue ?!

Comment: I don't know what's the root cause, but why would you define an onclick handler to report conversion just by clicking? Do you intent to report a conversion when the click and captcha both succeed, or you want to track all clicks regardless of succesful captch or not?
Regardless, I agree with @RoryMcCrossan that all logic should be in the submit itself. I don't like the idea of adding multiple handlers at different places.

Answer (score 0):

Is there only one form tag on your page? You have set the submit function for every single form element. You should probably set it by the form id.

Also, when you say "executes the action", do you mean sends the email? Or run the JS function? If it's the email, check to make sure that there is no other way to access the email code, including a refresh of the page.

Comment: I have just one form tag on my page ......and I mean with execute the action "sending email" sometimes it send email twice .... and sometimes send it one time so .... you have any idea about the cause of this strange issue?

Comment: After you submit the form, what happens? You have not shown the code that sends the email. Is there a "thank you page or something? What happens if you reload the browser on that page? Does it resubmit the form?